# Find all softlink files which link to a specific directory use pure find command

Tags: find, symlink

I have 2 link directories in ~, ~/PathA (a git directory) and ~/PathB. The ~/PathA is a subdirectory of ~/PathB. Those two are linked to other physical disk. I linked a lot of files to file under ~/PathA/config/ in my ~. **I want find out all those link files.** show "xxxxx -> yyyyy" format.

This method is often used when we use configuration files from old/other machine.

If I write a script or use pipe, it is easy can do but something ugly. But I want if only use **find** command I can do it.

Edit:
After test many time, I got it. The most important place is **-lname** and **-print**.

```
▶ find ~ -type l ! -path '/home/eexpss/磁盘' ! -path '/home/eexpss/bin' -lname '/home/eexpss/bin/config/*' -printf "%p -> %l\n"
/home/eexpss/.local/share/applications -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.local+share+applications
/home/eexpss/.local/share/nautilus/scripts -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.local+share+nautilus+scripts
/home/eexpss/.vimrc -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/fedora.vimrc
/home/eexpss/.proxy.pac -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.proxy.pac
/home/eexpss/.bash_aliases -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/fedora.bash_aliases
/home/eexpss/.icons -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.icons/
find: ‘/home/eexpss/磁盘/lost+found’: Permission denied
find: ‘/home/eexpss/磁盘/eexp/.gvfs’: Permission denied
/home/eexpss/.vim -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.vim
/home/eexpss/.gitconfig -> /home/eexpss/bin/config/.gitconfig
```

I will accept Stéphane Chazelas' answer. thanks.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Do you want to list _all_ symlinks in your home? Or only those that link to files on a different file system or outside your home?

Comment: Note that `-lname '/home/eexpss/bin/config/*'` would not find _relative_ symlinks that point inside `~/bin/config` (like a `/home/eexpss/x -> bin/config/x` or `/home/eexpss/etc/x -> ../bin/config/x`), or those expressed as `-> /home/eexpss/./bin/config/x` or `/home/eexpss/x/y` where `x` is a symlink to `bin/config`, etc.

Comment: `$f` would be expanded by the shell to the content of the `$f` shell variable. Possibly you meant `%f` (file name without leading path components)?

Comment: my mistake, type %p as $p. lol.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard `find` can't print any information about the found files by themselves except for their full paths. Some `find` implementations have extensions for that though.

For example, with GNU `find` (as found on most generic/traditional GNU/Linux distributions):

```
find ~ -type l -printf '%p -> %l\n'
```

Will print the symlinks in the format you're asking for, for symlinks found recursively (doing a *physical* traversal, that is not following symlinks to directories) in your home directory. Some `find` implementations also have a `-ls` predicate to output in a format similar to `ls -li` from which you may be able to extract the information.

If you wanted to do a *logical* traversal (follow symlinks to directories) and print that information, you couldn't do that with one `find` invocation alone (even with GNU `find`), but you could use `zsh`'s globbing to traverse the directories instead and use GNU `find` only to print the information:

```
find ~/***/*(D@) -printf '%p -> %l\n'
```

Or with any shell and GNU `find` (but several invocations):

```
find -L ~ -xtype l -exec sh -c '
  exec find "$@" -printf "%p -> %l\n"' sh {} +
```

To find the symlinks that *eventually* point to some *existing* file in `~/bin/config` (assuming that none of the components of `~/bin/config` are symlinks themselves), still with `zsh`:

```
find ~/**/*(D@e{'[[ $REPLY:A = ~/bin/config/* ]]'}) -printf '%p -> %l\n'
```

Comment: -L will make find error: a system loop detect. your last example is too complex to understand. I just use -lname, that's OK. thanks.